# Comments are assigned to wrong or related post

Tags: posts, comments

This issue is driving me nuts since weeks :(( Please help me.

The comments are assigned to related posts and are visible on other posts also.

For ex.

The page redirects to post "Sports" when I post the comment on "Food" But the same comment is visible on all the other posts like "Tours", "News" etc.,

Most likely, the comment is assigned to the last "related post"

To be more clear:

Sports Page
|
V
Related Posts - News, Tours, Food

Now, the comment goes to the post "Food"

here's the code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
        $image1 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image', true);
        $image2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image2', true);
        $image3 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image3', true);
        $image4 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image4', true);
        $image5 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image5', true);
        $image6 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image6', true);
        $image7 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image7', true);
        $image8 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image8', true);
        $image9 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image9', true);
        $image10 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_upload_image10', true);
        $folder_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'folder_name', true);
        $product_name = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'product_name', true);
        $product_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'product_id', true);

        $comingSoonButton = "<img src='http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/comingsoon.png'/>";

        $downloadButton = "<img src='http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/green-button/download-slash.png'/>";

        $buyButtonImage = "http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/red-button/buy-this-theme-slash.png";
        if($product_id == 22)
        {
            $buyButtonImage = "http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/buy-now-49.png";
        }

        $themeLinkNoMember = '<form name="PaymentForm" method="post" action="http://www.appdesignvault.com/dap/paypalCoupon.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$product_name.'" />
        <div><input class="trans" type="image" src="'. $buyButtonImage. '" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!" /></div>
        </form>';


        $themeLink = '<a href="http://www.appdesignvault.com/wp-content/uploads/' .$folder_name. '/themep.zip">'.$downloadButton.'</a>';


        $accessText = 'userhasccess';
        $accessShortCode = '[DAP hasAccessTo="'. $product_id .'"]'.$accessText.'[/DAP]';

        $attributes = array('isloggedin' => 'Y', 'errmsgtemplate' => 'Log in or Join');

        if($product_id == 0)
        {
            $dlLink = $comingSoonButton;
        }
        else
        {
            $accessContent = dap_shortcode($attributes, $accessShortCode);

            if(strpos($accessContent, $accessText) == true)
            {
                $dlLink = $themeLink;
            }
            else
            {
                $dlLink = $themeLinkNoMember;           
            }
        }

        ?>

        <!--BEGIN #portfolio-post-wrap -->
        <div id="portfolio-post-wrap" class="clearfix">

            <!--BEGIN .portfolio-sidebar -->
            <div class="portfolio-sidebar">

                <!--<h2 class="portfolio-title">the_title();</h2>-->

                <!--BEGIN .entry-content -->
                <div>
                    <?php
                        echo $dlLink;
                    ?>
                <!--END .entry-content -->
                </div>

                <?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'skill-type' ); ?>
                <?php $product_price = $product_id == 22 ? '$49' : '$70'; ?>

                <?php if ($product_id == 22){ echo "<p>Offer ends: 12th Jan 2012. </p>" ;} ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="callout_box">
                    <div class="theme-price">
                        <span class="theme-price"><?php echo $product_price; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="callout_box"><h4><strong><?php _e('Features:', 'framework'); ?></strong></h4>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <ul class="tax-list clearfix">
                            <li><span><img align="left" src="http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/xcode.png">&nbsp;Sample Project</span></li>
                            <li><span><img align="left" src="http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/magnify.png">&nbsp;Retina (@2x) files</span></li>
                            <li><span><img align="left" src="http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/xcode.png">&nbsp;iOS 5 compatible</span></li>
                            <li><span><img align="left" src="http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/photoshop.png">&nbsp;.PSD files</span></li>
                            <li><span><img align="left" src="http://www.appdesignvault.com/images/site/design.png">&nbsp;PNG Artwork</span></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="callout_box"><h4><strong><?php _e('Vault Tags:', 'framework'); ?></strong></h4>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <ul class="tax-list clearfix">
                            <?php foreach ($terms as $term) :  ?>
                            <li><span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <?php if(0){ ?>
                    <?php if(function_exists('dd_digg_generate')){dd_google1_generate('Normal');} ?>
                    <?php if(function_exists('dd_digg_generate')){dd_twitter_generate('Normal','emityme');} ?>
                    <?php if(function_exists('dd_digg_generate')){dd_fblike_generate('Like Box Count');} ?>
                    <?php if(function_exists('dd_digg_generate')){dd_digg_generate('Normal');} ?>
                    <?php }?>
                </div>


            <!--END .portfolio-sidebar -->
            </div>

            <!--BEGIN #portfolio-wrap -->
            <div id="portfolio-wrap">

                    <!--BEGIN .hentry -->
                    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                        <?php 
                        $add_info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_additional_info', true); 
                        $video_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_video_url', true);
                        $embeded_code = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_embed_code', true);
                        ?>

                        <?php if($video_url !='' || $embeded_code != '') : ?>

                        <!--BEGIN .video_slide -->
                        <div class="video_slide">

                            <?php if($add_info != '') : ?>
                            <!--BEGIN .video_info -->
                            <div class="video_info">
                                <?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($add_info)); ?>
                            </div>
                            <!--END .video_info -->
                            <?php endif; ?> 


                            <!--BEGIN .post_video -->
                            <div class="post_video">

                                <?php tz_video(get_the_ID()); ?>

                            <!--END .post_video -->
                            </div>

                        <!--END .video_slide -->
                        </div>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_portfolio_enable_slider', true) == 'yes') : ?>

                        <!--BEGIN #portfolio-slider .clearfix -->
                        <div id="portfolio-slider" class="clearfix">

                            <!--BEGIN .slides_container -->
                            <div class="slides_container">

                                <?php 
                                if($image1 != '') :

                                    $height = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_image1_height', true);

                                    if($height == '') :

                                        $height = getimagesize($image1);
                                        $height = $height[1];

                                    endif;

                                endif;
                                ?>
                                <div><img width="696" height="<?php echo $height; ?>" src="<?php echo $image1; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php if($image2 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image2; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image3 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image3; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image4 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image4; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image5 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image5; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image6 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image6; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image7 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image7; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image8 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image8; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image9 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image9; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($image10 != '') : ?>
                                <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image10; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <!--END .slides_container -->
                            </div>

                            <?php if($image2 != '' && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tz_portfolio_enable_slider', true) == 'yes') : ?>

                            <div id="line_wrap">
                                <div id="line"></div>
                            </div><!--line_wrap-->

                            <div id="portfolio_nav">

                                <div id="circles">

                                    <!--BEGIN .pagination -->
                                    <ul class="pagination">

                                        <?php if($image2 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image3 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image4 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image5 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image6 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image7 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image8 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image9 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if($image10 != '') : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    <!--END .pagination -->
                                    </ul>

                                </div><!--circles-->

                                <div id="arrows">

                                    <div id="left_arrow"><a class="prev" href="#">previous</a></div>

                                    <div id="right_arrow"><a class="next" href="#">next</a></div>

                                </div><!--arrows-->

                            </div><!--portfolio_nav-->
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <!--END #portfolio-slider -->
                        </div>
                        <?php else: ?>

                        <?php 
                        if($image1 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image1; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image2 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image2; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image3 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image3; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image4 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image4; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image5 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image5; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image6 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image6; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image7 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image7; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image8 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image8; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image9 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image9; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($image20 != '') : ?>
                        <div><img width="696" src="<?php echo $image10; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <!--END .hentry-->  
                    </div>

                    <div id="portfolio-info" class="clearfix">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>

            <!--END #portfolio-wrap-->
            </div>

        <!--END #portfolio-post-wrap -->
        </div>



        <hr>

        <!--BEGIN .portfolio-related -->
        <div id="portfolio-related" class="clearfix">

            <!--BEGIN .portfolio-sidebar -->
            <div class="portfolio-sidebar">

                <h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('tz_related_portfolio_title')); ?></h2>

                <!--BEGIN .entry-content -->
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('tz_related_portfolio_description')); ?>
                <!--END .entry-content -->
                </div>

            <!--END .portfolio-sidebar -->
            </div>

            <!--BEGIN #related-wrap -->
            <div id="related-wrap">

                <!--BEGIN #columns-wrap-->
                <ul id="columns-wrap" class="image-grid-three">

                    <?php global $post; 
                          $postId = $post->ID;
                          $query = get_posts_related_by_taxonomy($post->ID, 'skill-type');?>


                    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                          $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'skill-type' );  ?> 

                    <?php if(get_the_ID() != $postId) : ?>

                    <li>

                        <!--BEGIN .hentry -->
                        <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">   

                            <?php /* if the post has a WP 2.9+ Thumbnail */
                            if ( (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail()) ) { ?>
                            <div class="post-thumb">
                                <?php tz_lightbox(get_the_ID(), TRUE); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'framework'), get_the_title()); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php edit_post_link( __('edit', 'framework'), '<span class="edit-post">[', ']</span>' ); ?></h2>

                            <!--BEGIN .entry-content -->
                            <div class="entry-content">

                                <?php /*the_excerpt();*/ ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more-link"><?php _e('Read more...', 'framework'); ?></a>

                            <!--END .entry-content -->
                            </div>

                        <!--END .hentry-->  
                        </div>

                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                <!--END #columns-wrap-->  
                </ul>

            <!--END #related-wrap -->
            </div>

        <!--END #portfolio-related -->
        </div>

        <?php comments_template('', true); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add [`wp_reset_postdata();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after the `endwhile;` of the 'related posts' loop.

Comment: Awesome....!!!! I already tried the option but was putting the code at the after the related post... thanks for pointing me to the right direction :-D

Comment: Thanks guys but I want to ask in which page is this code ? I have the same problem

Comment: @humphrey - there is no general direct answer to your question. try and check single.php of your theme, or whatever template part gets called from that file. it might also be caused by a plugin which generates the related posts, you could try to ask in the forum of your currently used theme, or contact the developer of your theme for help.

Comment: This is the best advise thanks